# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar todos los votos de la aplicacion de encuestas de django?

Tags: python, django

Querría saber cómo puedo mostrar todos los votos en la vista de resultado de la aplicaciones de encuestas de Django, la primera que aparece en todos los tutoriales.

Tengo esto, pero así me muestra el resultado solo de una:

```
<h1>{{ pregunta.pregunta }}</h1>

<ul>
{% for respuesta in pregunta.respuesta_set.all %}
    <li>{{ respuesta.respuesta }} -- {{ respuesta.votos}} voto{{ respuesta.votos|pluralize }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Éste es mi código para views.py:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'ProyectoF/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'lista_upreguntas'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Devuelve las 5 ultimas preguntas."""
        return Pregunta.objects.order_by('-prgFecha')[:5]


class DetallesView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Pregunta
    template_name = 'ProyectoF/detalles.html'


class ResultadosView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Pregunta
    template_name = 'ProyectoF/resultados.html'
    total = 


def votos(request, pregunta_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Pregunta, pk=pregunta_id)
    try:
        respuesta_ele = p.respuesta_set.get(pk=request.POST['respuesta'])
    except (KeyError, Respuesta.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the Pregunta voting form.
        return render(request, 'ProyectoF/detalles.html', {
            'pregunta': p,
            'error_message': "No has selecionado ninguna respuesta",
        })
    else:
        respuesta_ele.votos += 1
        respuesta_ele.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('ProyectoF:resultados', args=(p.id,)))
```

Comment: Tal y como está ahora mismo la pregunta es un poco amplia. Podrías concretarla un poco añadiendo el código que lleves, lo que hayas intentado, y los problemas/errores que te estés encontrando.

Comment: Tengo 4 preguntas en la aplicacion de encuestas, y cuando voto, me sale el resultado de la pregunta en cuestion, pero lo que quiero es que se me muestre todos los resultados de los votos de las preguntas...

Comment: En la view recupera los votos y pásalos a través del context.
`votos = respuesta.votos.all()`
En el template solo deberás referenciar a la variable 'votos'. 
`{{ votos }}`

Comment: Si tu archivo models.py es exactamente como el tutorial no será posible mostrar todos los votos, ya que el único dato que tenemos es una variable donde se guarda la cantidad de votos, no existe un objeto "Voto" O podrias mostrar tu archivo models.py para entender mejor